# аналог application в фрагментах

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

в activity есть функция application , мне нужен её аналог

Comment: Что за аналог application? Для чего? Какие функции, например, должен выполнять такой аналог? Чем обычный application вам не подходит? Раскройте чуть больше суть вашей проблемы. Отредактировать вопрос можно по кнопке "править" под вопросом.

Comment: У каждого фрагмента есть activity, у которой "есть функция application(getApplication())". Какой аналог? Пользуйтесь оригиналом.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585702/how-to-get-application-object-into-fragment-class

Comment: getApplicationContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

requireActivity().application вот

Answer (score 0):

В Android-приложении на Kotlin можно использовать фрагменты для создания пользовательского интерфейса. Чтобы работать с фрагментами, нужно использовать класс Fragment и его методы, которые позволяют создавать, добавлять, заменять и удалять фрагменты.

Вместо использования класса Application, который используется для работы с приложением в целом, в фрагментах можно использовать методы жизненного цикла фрагмента, такие как onCreate, onCreateView, onResume и т.д., чтобы выполнить нужные действия в различных состояниях фрагмента.

Например, для создания фрагмента можно создать класс, который наследуется от Fragment:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // создание пользовательского интерфейса фрагмента
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false)
        // выполнение нужных действий
        return view
    }
}
```

Затем этот фрагмент можно добавить в активити, используя фрагментный менеджер:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, MyFragment())
        .commit()
```

Здесь `R.id.fragment_container` - это идентификатор контейнера, в который нужно добавить фрагмент.

Для более подробной информации по работе с фрагментами можно ознакомиться с документацией: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/index.html

Comment: мне нужно аналог application(а не Application)

Comment: отредактируйте ваш вопрос и добавьте деталей, чтобы можно было понять точнее, что вы хотите. вы в контексте проблемы, а мы тут нет

Comment: сделано как просили